# Deserialising string list in GSON?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, gson

I am trying to save a string list in a jsonobject and deserialise it on load. When I am saving the list, I am creating a JsonObject and adding it as a property by using the GSON.toJson. I have created a String arraylist serialiser to serialise the item and when I check my mongo database it appears to be saving as a jsonArray but when I try to deserialise it, it tells me that it is not a JsonArray.

Here is my code:

Order object:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Order {

    private final UUID id;
    private final String table;

    private short numberOfPeople;
    private LocalDate timeOfOrder = LocalDate.now();

    private String staffInCharge = "";

    private List<String> order = new ArrayList<>();
    private String note = "";
}
```

The @RequiredArgumentsConstructor just creates a constructor for me so I dont have to do public Order() etc

Imports of the Serialise and Deserialise class:

```
import com.google.gson.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import me.oscar.orderbird.OrderBird;
import me.oscar.orderbird.gson.GsonUtil;
import me.oscar.orderbird.mongo.MongoUtils;
import me.oscar.orderbird.profile.food.Food;
import me.oscar.orderbird.profile.order.Order;
import me.oscar.orderbird.profile.staff.Staff;
import me.oscar.orderbird.profile.table.Table;
import org.bson.Document;

import java.util.*;
```

Serialise:

```
        if (!this.orders.isEmpty()){
            JsonArray orderArray = new JsonArray();
            this.orders.values().forEach(order -> {
                JsonObject ordersObect = new JsonObject();
                ordersObect.addProperty("id", order.getId().toString());
                ordersObect.addProperty("name", order.getTable());
                ordersObect.addProperty("note", order.getNote());
                ordersObect.addProperty("numberOfPeople", order.getNumberOfPeople());
                ordersObect.addProperty("staffInCharge", order.getStaffInCharge());
                ordersObect.addProperty("orderItems", GsonUtil.GSON.toJson(order.getOrder()));
                orderArray.add(ordersObect);
            });
            document.put("orders", orderArray.toString());

        }
```

Deserialise:

```
        if (document.containsKey("orders")) {
            if (document.get("orders") instanceof String) {
                JsonArray ordersArray = PARSER.parse(document.getString("orders")).getAsJsonArray();

                for (JsonElement jsonElement : ordersArray) {
                    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                    try {
                        Order order = new Order(UUID.fromString(jsonObject.get("id").getAsString()), jsonObject.get("name").getAsString());
                        order.setNote(jsonObject.get("note").getAsString());
                        order.setNumberOfPeople(jsonObject.get("numberOfPeople").getAsShort());
                        order.setStaffInCharge(jsonObject.get("staffInCharge").getAsString());
                        order.setOrder(GsonUtil.GSON.fromJson(jsonObject.get("orderItems").getAsJsonObject(), ArrayList.class));
                        this.orders.put(jsonObject.get("name").getAsString(), order);

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

ArrayListAdapter:

```
package me.oscar.orderbird.gson.impl;

import com.google.gson.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StringArrayAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<List<String>>, JsonSerializer<List<String>> {
    @Override
    public List<String> deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonArray jsonArray = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++){
            values.set(i, jsonArray.get(i).getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString());
        }
        return values;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(List<String> stringList, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
        for (String string : stringList) {
            jsonArray.add(new JsonPrimitive(string));
        }
        return jsonArray;
    }
}
```

When I attempt to set the order I am getting the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: "[\n  \"Steak\"\n]"
```

Comment: can you add `Order` object class as well?

Comment: Also please add all the imports, which will help SO members to rectify the issue

Comment: @dkb I have added what you asked me to

Comment: Also I see there are unknowns like `GsonUtil`, `PARSER`, `this.orders.values()` --> values() of list/set/array ?

Comment: Check this once: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @dkb PARSER is just a JsonParser the code is just private JsonParser PARSER = new JsonParser() and GsonUtil is just the creation of the Gson Instance     public static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(ArrayList.class, new StringArrayAdapter())
            .setPrettyPrinting()
            .serializeNulls()
            .create();

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your implementation

1. While changing from Object to Document, you need to preserve property class type for `orderItems`

change

```java
ordersObect.addProperty("orderItems", GsonUtil.GSON.toJson(order.getOrder()));
```

TO

```java
ordersObect.addProperty("orderItems", GSON.toJson(order.getOrder(), ArrayList.class));
```

2. While reading from Document, need to read as the same class type

change

```java
GsonUtil.GSON.fromJson(jsonObject.get("orderItems").getAsJsonObject(), ArrayList.class)
```

TO

```java
GSON.fromJson(jsonObject.get("orderItems").getAsString(),ArrayList.class)
```

So working code is as below:

```java
import com.Order;
import com.StringArrayAdapter;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import org.bson.Document;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

JsonParser PARSER = new JsonParser();
Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(ArrayList.class, new StringArrayAdapter())
        .setPrettyPrinting()
        .serializeNulls()
        .create();
Document document = new Document();
Map<String, Order> orders = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    Order order = new Order(UUID.randomUUID(), "" + i);
    orders.put(order.getTable(), order);
}

// SO Post Code
if (!orders.isEmpty()) {
    JsonArray orderArray = new JsonArray();
    orders.values().forEach(order -> {
        JsonObject ordersObect = new JsonObject();
        ordersObect.addProperty("id", order.getId().toString());
        ordersObect.addProperty("name", order.getTable());
        ordersObect.addProperty("note", order.getNote());
        ordersObect.addProperty("numberOfPeople", order.getNumberOfPeople());
        ordersObect.addProperty("staffInCharge", order.getStaffInCharge());
        ordersObect.addProperty("orderItems", GSON.toJson(order.getOrder(), ArrayList.class));
        orderArray.add(ordersObect);
    });
    document.put("orders", orderArray.toString());
}

System.out.println("document: " + document);
Map<String, Order> readOrders = new HashMap<>();
if (document.containsKey("orders")) {
    if (document.get("orders") instanceof String) {
        JsonArray ordersArray = PARSER.parse(document.getString("orders")).getAsJsonArray();

        for (JsonElement jsonElement : ordersArray) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
            try {
                Order order = new Order(UUID.fromString(jsonObject.get("id").getAsString()), jsonObject.get("name").getAsString());
                order.setNote(jsonObject.get("note").getAsString());
                order.setNumberOfPeople(jsonObject.get("numberOfPeople").getAsShort());
                order.setStaffInCharge(jsonObject.get("staffInCharge").getAsString());
                order.setOrder((ArrayList<String>)GSON.fromJson(jsonObject.get("orderItems").getAsString(), ArrayList.class));
                readOrders.put(jsonObject.get("name").getAsString(), order);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Orders read : " + readOrders);
```

OUTPUT:

```java
document: Document{{orders=[{"id":"e853617a-b516-4daf-ba6c-e5d731c556de","name":"0","note":"","numberOfPeople":0,"staffInCharge":"","orderItems":"[]"},{"id":"31004bbd-164d-4e64-b468-7021e1c21c39","name":"1","note":"","numberOfPeople":0,"staffInCharge":"","orderItems":"[]"}]}}
Orders read : {0=Order(id=e853617a-b516-4daf-ba6c-e5d731c556de, table=0, numberOfPeople=0, timeOfOrder=2021-06-16, staffInCharge=, order=[], note=), 1=Order(id=31004bbd-164d-4e64-b468-7021e1c21c39, table=1, numberOfPeople=0, timeOfOrder=2021-06-16, staffInCharge=, order=[], note=)}
```

Comment: This gives me the error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
 at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:448) at me.oscar.orderbird.gson.impl.StringArrayAdapter.deserialize(StringArrayAdapter.java:23)
 at me.oscar.orderbird.gson.impl.StringArrayAdapter.deserialize(StringArrayAdapter.java:9)
 at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:69)
 at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
 at me.oscar.orderbird.profile.Profile.fromDocument(Profile.java:164)

Comment: you should not get that error, just copy-paste the above code and run.